# Time series or date time in R

Tags: r, datetime, timestamp, time-series

I'm browsing some documentation and I am wondering how to approach my design. I have a large data set with plenty of columns and a timestamp column as well. However, I am still not sure whether to use the time stamp or just convert my data into time series and specify the data ranges myself. The goal of the project is to have a web app (shiny based) where you can perform different types of visualization, based on different criteria - date, time, plotting different columns etc.

I already checked the "Little Book of R for Time Series!" and a lot about POSIXt, timeDate. I was even considering using rCharts but I decided that it will be better to perform the filtering based on a range predefined by the user. Any kind of ideas, suggestions are more than welcome. Thank you in advance!

Regards,
Boris

Answer (score 1):

For using a time stamp, just use the strptime() function, specifying the format as in the examples below, which converts a SAS date time stamp to an R date time stamp.

See help(DateTimeClasses) for descriptions of each format.

> %b - Abbreviated month name in the current locale. (Also matches full name on input.)

```
sasdate="13MAY2015:05:04:21.000000"
rdate=strptime(sasdate, format="%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%s")
rdate
## "2015-05-13 05:04:21"
```

Examine the format argument in the strptime() function:

%d specifys the two digit day, %b specifies the month, %Y specifies the 4 digit year and so forth.  Use these in conjunction with any semicolons, dashes, ect that is in your data to match the format of your data.